# How to use a duplex wcf service to distribute messages to all clients?

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

I am building a simple duplex wcf service. In this service clients send messages to the server and the server distributes the message to all connected clients. However, despite the fact that I defined the ServiceBehavior attribute as
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)], only the client who sent the message receives it back from the server, while the other clients do not. I verified that there is just one instance of the server running.
What did I do wrong? I looked at other similar questions on the web, and they all say that I should define InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, which I already did.

Comment: show us how you are sending the message back. Make sure you send it to all connected clients. You could have them call a register method and keep a list on the server and loop the list.

Comment: Obviously SignalR is just for such cases. It would be too difficult for WCF.

Comment: Here is how I am sending the messages:
IMessageServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageServiceCallback>();
callback.SendMessage(message);

I also tried to have separate callback object for each user and loop over all these objects, but it does not work either.

Comment: Do not add code as a comment. Edit your post and add it there./

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a callback Contract. So that server will reply back to client.
Check the below tutorial for Implementing Callback Contract
[Click here](http://wcftutorial.net/callback-service.aspx)

Also check the below Project Event Notification server. This project is doing similar things what you want.

[CodeProject Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26160/A-simplified-non-topic-based-Event-Notification-Se)

Feel free to ask me if you need any more clarification

You need to maintain the clistList as shown in the code snippet.

```
List<IMessageServiceCallback> clientList = new List<IMessageServiceCallback>();
public void Register()
{ 
    IMessageServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageServiceCallback>(); 
    clientList.add(callback);
}
```

When you want to broadcast this message. You can iterate through the list and call the callback function to send message to clients.

Comment: of course I defined a contract. Here it is:     [ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IMessageServiceCallback))]
    public interface IMessageService
    {

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string s);
    }

    public interface IMessageServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string s);
    }

Comment: Do you maintain a instancecontext of all clients in a list or array?
List<IMessageServiceCallback> clientList = new List<IMessageServiceCallback>();
public void Register()
{
    IMessageServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageServiceCallback>();
clientList.add(callback);
}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked at the links and I manage to implement the service I wanted. In short, I need to have a callback object for each connected client. Then, I loop over all these objects in order to send messages to all the connected clients.

Comment: @user207809 - consider awarding this as the answer if it helped you arrive at a solution. Also, don't post code in comments. Consider adding the code to your question using an edit.

Comment: @kalidoss Do not post code in comment. Instead edit your answer to include the comment.